# Design of a class regarding components

Tags: object, design-patterns

Lets abstract say i want to program two classes that have a relation of 1 to n(many) and I don't know what the best approach to take. Programming Language doesn't matter!!!

> class Parent
>        {
>   string name;
>   date birthdate;
>   array children[]; 
>   // is it better to declare here an array of children and add childrenobjects to >this or is it better at the childclass to have an variable pointer to an object of type Parent????
>
> ... constructor setters getters ....
>    
>   function addChild(Childtype childvar)
>            {
>            this->children push childvar
>            }
>   function removeChild(Childtype childvar)
>            {
>            }
>   
>   function saveDB()
>            {
>            //what do I save there only parent or also the children that were created during runtime >and added to an instance of this object????
>   
>            insert into relational_db_table values (name, birthdate);
>   
>            //really not sure whats the best and why
>            foreach key->value of children do
>                     {
>                     child->saveDB()
>                     }
>            }
>   }
>   
>   class Child {
>   Parent myparent; 
>  
>   string name;
>   string description;
>   ....constructors setters getters... //doesnt matter
>   
>   saveDB {    //
>    INsert into relational_db_table VALUES (name, description, myparent);
>   }
>   }

So i will repeat now my 2 questions:
1. What is best and why? 
a) to declare at the parent class an array which holds the children 
b) to declare a variable at the child class that holds a reference to the parent object
c) do both of the above

2. Regarding saving to databases what is the best and why?
   If i take a) form 1st question approach do i have to save the children as i wrote from the parent class cause i cant see how else i can save the children to the db for later use. is here any othere method??

If I take b I will have to manage somehow the childrens of a parent in memory that will be don with a collection no problem extra which is not a problem. but in this case if anything changes to a propery i can save it separatly hmmm not sure.

Please thing of these questions with a database in the back of the application the database is not necessary a relational one its fine for me also with nosql databases. I'm only interested to do design these classes very good so in future if something has to be changed the things will be easy to change and i want do use the best programming patterns possible. I have read also almost all of the existing OOP programing patterns around but i still cant decide what to do here best.

PS: sorry code is not tabbed

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with first approach,

```
class Parent {

    private String id;
    private List<Child> childList;

    public List<Child> getChildList() {
        return childList;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

class Child {

    private String id; 

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

You can insert data of multiple parent as,

```
    List<Parent> parentList = getParentList();
    for (Parent parent : parentList) {
        String parentId = parent.getId();
        for (Child child : parent.getChildList()) {
            String childId = child.getId(); // Parent info
            // Add to DB - you can pass parent info & child info
            // insert parentId, childId 
        }

    }
```

> Why not each child having reference to its parent?

In this case,  you need to have a list which contain children, which will break OOPS concept. (For Eg: Parent, as an object need to know about its children)

> How is it useful for DB?

In this case, you can easily navigate to required parent (If not require for now, for future) & insert ONLY its corresponding children elements into DB. If you take option 2, you need to loop over ALL child elements (Which may be VERY long - Not efficient)

> Were would you place the functions to insert the data into the database?

Commented in code.

Comment: 1. Ok can you explain why?

Comment: 1. Ok can you explain why? 2. Were would you place the functions to insert the data into the database, if you have in each class a function for the corresponding table in the DB, then how do you handle the insert in the children table since you have to save there the parent? Lets say child table has following structure (child_id, child_name, ..., parent_id) do you intend to send the parent_id as a parameter?

Comment: So if I understand right you suggest NOT to put the DB related stuff in any class i mean by this not in Parent and not in Child and eventually do another class that handels the DB read and write?  Is that so?

Comment: That is design option. You can choose to have a utility class which will handle all types of DB operation. OR you can ask each class to know how to handle DB operation related to its type. OR if this operation is not required to be reused, just have code for DB at required point!!!